# How can I check if an object is of a generic type?

Tags: c#

For the sake of argument, I have an `object`. I can't modify the signature of my function because I am extending someone else's class.

To give a concrete example, I have the following:

```
class Foo<T> : SomeBaseClass
{
    public override MyFunction(object value)
    {
        // TODO: Figure out if value is an instance of Foo, though I don't care
        // what type was associated with it.
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make sure that `value` is some instance of a `Foo` type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if you want to check whether it's *exactly* a `Foo<something>` it's fairly easy:

```
Type type = value.GetType();
if (!type.IsGenericType)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Not a generic type");
}
if (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(Foo<>))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Not the right generic type");
}
```

If you need to decide whether it's *some type derived from `Foo<T>`* it's slightly harder - because you don't necessarily know where it'll be generic. For example, it could be:

```
class Bar : Foo<string>
```

or

```
class Baz<T> : Foo<T>
```

One alternative to make things easier might be to introduce another non-generic class:

```
abstract class Foo : SomeBaseClass

class Foo<T> : Foo
```

Then you can just do:

```
if (value is Foo)
```

Of course that would also allow for other types deriving from `Foo`. In many cases that wouldn't really be a problem, but it depends on your exact situation. You could also put any members which don't need to refer to `T` into `Foo`, so you could access them in cases like this where you don't care about `T`.

Comment: I didn't know you could use a generic type without a type parameter like that... very nice. At the moment, I'm only worried about the former case, but the latter is good to know too.

Answer (score 2):

You might try to invoke [GetGenericTypeDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx) on `value.GetType()`. This will basically give you either `Foo<>` or throw an exception. To avoid the latter, check `IsGenericType` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it if you are overriding from a base class.

You could do something along these lines though. The big disadvantage is that you loose the compile time type checking and leave it down to the runtime.

```
class Foo<T> : SomeBaseClass
{
    public override MyFunction(object value)
    {
       if(value.GetType() != typeof(T))
       {
          // wrong type throw exception or similar
       }
    }
}
```